# Resize QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt, resize, qgraphicspixmapitem

I need to place a clickable picture on the QGraphicsScene. This is how I did it:

```
class myGraphicsPixmapItem: public QGraphicsPixmapItem 
{
public:
    myGraphicsPixmapItem() { }

    ~myGraphicsPixmapItem() {}

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Clicked!";

    }
};


QPixmap pic;
pic.load(":/img/pic.png");

QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
view = new GraphicsView(scene);

myGraphicsPixmapItem* pixmapItem = new myGraphicsPixmapItem;
pixmapItem->setPixmap(pic);
scene->addItem(pixmapItem);
```

But I don't know how to make it smaller. Please tell, how to make smaller QGraphicsPixmapItem or is there another way to place a clickable and resizable picture on the QGraphicsScene?

Comment: You could scale the item with [QGraphicsItem#setScale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale). Or just set a new [scaled QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) on the item.

Answer (score 1):

you should use scaled [QPixmap::scaled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) instead of QGraphicsPixmapItem .
sample code :

```
QPixmap bgPixmap(fileName);
QPixmap scaled = bgPixmap.scaled(QSize(64, 64));
```

and use scaled as your QPixmap .